# When trying to define transformer for a batch transform process for a sklearn estimator, i am getting an error

Tags: scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

When trying to define transformer for a batch transform process for a sklearn estimator, i am getting the following error : TypeError: **init**() got multiple values for argument 'entry_point'"

These are the steps i followed:

**STEP 1:**

```
from sagemaker.sklearn.estimator import SKLearn

script_path = 'transformer.py'

sklearn_preprocessor = SKLearn(
    entry_point=script_path,
    role=role,
    train_instance_type="ml.c4.xlarge",
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)
```

**STEP 2:**

```
sklearn_preprocessor.fit({'train': "s3://training-data/train.csv"})
```

training was successful.

**STEP 3:**

```
transformer = sklearn_preprocessor.transformer(
    instance_count=1, 
    instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
    assemble_with = 'Line',
    output_path='s3://training-data/transformed.csv',
    accept = 'text/csv')
```

Error at Step3:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'entry_point'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was reported to the AWS Sagemaker Python SDK's Github repository
    https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/974

It seems like the issue has been resolved with PR https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/pull/978
Looking at the CHANGELOG, the fix was released in version v1.36.3. Updating the SDK to a later version should resolve the issue